# How to deploy Express NodeJS project to Centos server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, centos

I have never deployed a NodeJS application and therefore don't know how to do it.
I have worked and completed a Express NodeJS application that uses MongoDB as its database.

While working on the project, I would usually use "npm start" to test the current progress of the application (by checking it on port 3000).

To run the project, I have bought a virtual private server that runs in Centos.
I have my files on the server and have used "npm start" to make sure everything works fine. I usually do this by SSHing into the server and working from there.

Now, how exactly am I supposed to deploy the project such that I can exit the SSH session and the project would still be live on the server IP address.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hi @Nedaaa - Have you tried the solution I provided you? If it solved you problem, please remember to "accept" my answer to give it a green check mark.

Comment: hello @rdgd, unfortunately, I have been having technical difficulties with the server and will be trying your solution when the server is running again. Thank you for providing a solution though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is the need to run the NodeJS process in the background. There are other ways to do this, but in order to manage your application well, I would recommend that you use a NodeJS process manager.

Have a look at [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) This is a popular solution, the documentation is good, and should work just fine for you.

I would recommend installing it globally on your VPS `npm install -g pm2` and then navigate to your project root and run `pm2 start whatever-your-main-js-file-is-named.js` You can then see information on all processes with the command `pm2 list` and there are several other commands for understanding more about the processes that you are running, just check out their docs or their `pm2 --help`

Comment: pm2 starts running the project but errors immediately and I am not able to find a way to see what is occurring the error.

Comment: Any other recommendations?

Comment: You can try looking at the pm2 logs to troubleshoot the issue. They should be in `~/.pm2/logs`. If you want to try another process manager, I would say the other most popular process manager is foreverjs https://github.com/foreverjs/forever Give that a shot. If that doesn't work, then you know the issue is not with the process manager itself and instead with you application or greater server configuration. I say troubleshoot the issue first before throwing different tooling at it.

Comment: I checked all of `~/.pm2/logs/app-error.log`,  `~/.pm2/logs/app-out.log`, and `~/.pm2/pids/app.pid`. all three files are unfortunately empty.. i guess I will try foreverjs. Hopefully that works.

Comment: Should I be changing my app.js in any way? Right now, it just has the routes for all the pages and stuff. I haven't added anything special to it to make it work with any special software other than what is needed for the project to run.

Comment: Not necessarily. I can't say for sure without actually looking at the source code.

Comment: okay, I just got it to work with pm2. Since I was using express, I had to add to the app.js file to listen on a port. That helped. I will be editing your comment @rdgd to add the solution that worked for anyone who might need it in the future.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Yes, with express you should be telling the app to listen on a specific port.